# How can I derive the Legendre function of first kind in terms of the hypergeometric function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, legendre-functions

I was reading in Wikipedia about [Legendre's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Legendre%27s_differential_equation). I was particularly interested in the simple case of the equation given by
$$
\left(1-x^2\right)y'' -2xy' + \lambda(\lambda+1)y = 0 \tag{1}
$$
In the article, it is stated that one of the two linearly independent solutions to $(1)$ is given by
$$
P_{\lambda}(x) =  \,_2F_1 \left(-\lambda, \lambda+1; 1; \frac{1-x}{2}\right) \tag{2}
$$
where $\,_2F_1$ represents the hypergeometric function. Since by definition, the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;t)$ is a solution to the [hypergeometric differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation) given by
$$
t(1-t) \ \ddot{y} + \left[c-(a+b+1)t \right] \dot{y} - ab\,y = 0 \tag{3}
$$
if $(2)$ is a solution to $(1)$ then I should be able to re-write $(1)$ to look like $(3)$ with the corresponding parameters. With this in mind, taking
\begin{align*}
a &= - \lambda\\
b &= \lambda +1\\
c &= 1\\
t & =  \frac{1-x}{2}
\end{align*}
From where we also get that
$$
\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt} =  \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot  \underbrace{\frac{dx}{dt}}_{\color{blue}{-2}} = -2y'
$$
which also tells us that
$$
\ddot{y} = -2 y''
$$
Substituting this into $(3)$ gives
\begin{align}
\frac{1-x}{2}\left(1-\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\ddot{y} + &\left[1-\left(-\lambda+(\lambda +1)+1\right)\frac{1-x}{2} \right] \dot{y} - (-\lambda)(\lambda +1)y = 0\\
\implies  \frac{1}{4}\left(1-x^2 \right)\left(-2 y''\right) +& \left[1-2\frac{1-x}{2} \right] \left(-2 y'\right) +\lambda(\lambda +1)y = 0\\
\implies \left(1-x^2 \right)y'' &+ 4x y' -2 \lambda(\lambda +1)y = 0 \tag{4}
\end{align}
and although $(4)$ looks really similar to $(1)$, they're not the same equation.

Could anyone tell me where did I make a mistake? Or alternatively, does anyone know another simple way to show that the Legendre function can be written in terms of the hypergeometric function? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proposed derivation, it is correctly establish that $\dot y=-2y'$ but we have also $\ddot y=4y''$ (and not $\ddot y=-2y''$ as stated).
With this correction, the ODE are identical.

Comment: Ohhhh, of course! I forgot to apply the chain rule correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From Abramowitz and Stegun, 'Legendre functions are those special cases of the hypergeometric function for which a quadratic transformation exists.'  There is then a list of some twenty formulas, eq. 15.4.7-15.4.26.

Comment: I do understand that they're a specific case, but my question is that I don't know how to _show_ that they're a specific case starting from their definitions as solutions to differential equations.

Comment: I was answering the 'alternatively' part of the question.  Quadratic transformations of the hypergeometric function are handled in many textbooks.  Admittedly, Abramowitz and Stegun is more a compilation of formulas.  Look at eq. 15.6.6 for 'Riemann's P Function' which is probably the way you'll need to go if insisting on on a path from differential equations.

Comment: I see. I'll take a look at the equations you mention. Thank you for your answer!